# Rails 5: can't order after group and count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

In my `subscribers` table I have duplicate emails, so I want to count these. I'm doing this in the Rails console:

`Subscriber.select("email, count(*)").group(:email).order("count (*) desc")`

This results in the following query to my `PostgreSQL` db:

`SELECT email, count(*) FROM "subscribers" GROUP BY "subscribers"."email" ORDER BY count (*) desc`

The strange thing is, although this query works fine when run directly from the db, it doesn't work in the Rails console, which returns:

`#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Subscriber id: nil, email: "a@a.com">, #<Subscriber id: nil, email: "b@b.com">, #<Subscriber id: nil, email: "c@c.com">]>`

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works but your subscriber objects don't have that aggregated field (and you are not extracting the others). Give it a name

```
subscribers = Subscriber.select("email, COUNT(*) AS counter").group(:email).order("COUNT (*) desc")
```

Extract these fields

```
subscribers.each { |s| puts s.email, s.counter }
```

Comment: Great! Did you name it as `counter` instead of `count` to avoid reserved methods? Just curious.

Comment: I did not think about that but it's probably a good idea avoid count :)